# htop CPU% at ~100% but bar graph shows every core much lower

Tags: cpu-usage, htop

I'm using Debian 9 to host a game server. Specifically, I'm hosting about 10 instances of the game Don't Starve Together.

The other day I noticed one of those instances (which was getting a lot of player activity) exhibit performance issues. When I loaded up `htop` I saw that `CPU%` was reporting `101%` but the bar graphs at the top were not showing any cores at much above 50%.

[image]

To my knowledge, `CPU%` shows a sum of the percentages used of each core by a process, so exceeding 100% is normal and no core being above 50% is also normal (it just means the process is quite multi-threaded), however I believe Don't Starve Together is almost entirely a single-threaded application (with minimal multi threading for networking).

One of the bar graphs at the top should be at least over 90%, but none are. Why isn't one of the bar graphs at the top not over 90%? My processor is an i7-6700K (4 core, 8 thread - [spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88195/intel-core-i7-6700k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) )

Comment: Probably not what's happening, but if a program is I/O bound, or network bound, or suffering from lock contention, it may suffer from terrible performance without maxing out a CPU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Over time, the operating system schedules threads on different CPU cores, so the 101% reported for your processes are potentially distributed over all 8 bars.